# 7Zip exclude all subdirectories

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

In my test my folder structure is as follows:

```
D:\Data\1.db
D:\Data\2.db
D:\Data\3.db
D:\Data\FolderA\1.db
D:\Data\FolderA\2.db
D:\Data\FolderA\3.db
```

This is a simple example to my complex real world situation.  I'm using the include list to backup only the `.db` files (and many many other file types), but I don't want ANY sub-directories zipped, but I may not know the sub-directories names.

So the question is, - how do I compress files using an include list while excluding all sub-directories when the name of the sub-directories is unknown?

I've tried the following from my `D:\Data` folder with the results in brackets

```
7za a -t7z D:\Backups\data.zip -r- -ir@"D:\data\include.txt" :: (sub-dirs included)
```

I changed the `-r-` from the line above to the below with results in brackets

```
-xr-    [incorrect command line]
-xr-!*  [nothing zipped]
-xr!*   [nothing zipped]
```

Comment: Found the answer quoted below
If you want to use 7z, the tricky part seems to be persuading it not to recurse; the documentation's indicated -r- switch appears to be non-functional, and the suggested workaround from the software's author is to exclude subdirectories with the wildcard expression -x!*/

Comment: I think it would be good if you move solution you found to the answer and accepted it as answer. It is absolutely legal and encouraged way in such situation when OP found answer to own question.

Comment: N.P. By the way, if you using `-t7z` option then archive's file extension must be `.7z` instead of `zip` since created archive will be in 7-zip format and any program that handling `zip` file extension (windows explorer) will choke on such archives

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer quoted below If you want to use [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/), the tricky part seems to be persuading it not to recurse; the documentation's indicated `-r-` switch appears to be non-functional, and the suggested workaround from the software's author is to exclude subdirectories with the wildcard expression `-x!*/` on Linux, and `-x!*\` on Windows.

Comment: To be more exact:
`7z.exe a test.zip C:\directory\* -x!*/ -tzip`